# populate listview from database with json and php

Tags: javascript, php, android, json, listview

i'm trying to populate the listview by following the tutorial here http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html, but the data is not showing up when i press the getData button. it seems i fail to pass the array from php to my android app using json, so i need help

Edit : recently i was able to pass the value from php, but i was unable to set the value in listview, when i run the activity, the logcat output text will be like this :

```js
06-04 09:10:23.844: D/JSON Parser(4058): {"pendaftar":[[{"no_pendaftaran":"AD-15-001","nama_lengkap":"Wanda"},{"no_pendaftaran":"AD-15-002","nama_lengkap":"Skndje"},{"no_pendaftaran":"AD-15-003","nama_lengkap":"Aksn"}]]}
```

and i edit my php code:

```js
 //fetching all the rows from the query
 $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
 $response["pendaftar"][]= $row;
    
 echo json_encode($response);
```

so here's my activity which will display the listview :

```js
package subactivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii.JSONParser;
import id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SeleksiNilai extends Activity {

 ListView list;
    TextView noPendaftaran;
    TextView namaPendaftar;
    Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> calonSiswa = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    
  //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.110/smkkimmanuel2/seleksiNilai.php";
 
    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_OS = "pendaftar";
    private static final String TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN = "no_pendaftaran";
    private static final String TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP = "nama_lengkap";
    
    JSONArray pendaftar = null;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_seleksi_nilai);
  calonSiswa = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
   
        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 new GetData().execute();
 
            }
        });
 }

 private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
            noPendaftaran = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noPendaftar);
            namaPendaftar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.namaPendaftar);
           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SeleksiNilai.this);
           pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
           pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
           pDialog.setCancelable(true);
           pDialog.show();

       }

       @Override
       protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

           // Getting JSON from URL
           JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
           return json;
       }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                   // Getting JSON Array from URL
                   pendaftar = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                   for(int i = 0; i < pendaftar.length(); i++){
                   JSONObject c = pendaftar.getJSONObject(i);

                   // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                   String ver = c.getString(TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN);
                   String name = c.getString(TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP);

                   // Adding value HashMap key => value

                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                   map.put(TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN, ver);
                   map.put(TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP, name);

                   calonSiswa.add(map);
                   list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SeleksiNilai.this, calonSiswa,
                           R.layout.single_item_seleksi_nilai,
                           new String[] { TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN,TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP }, new int[] {
                                   R.id.noPendaftar,R.id.namaPendaftar});

                   list.setAdapter(adapter);
                   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
       int position, long id) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Toast.makeText(SeleksiNilai.this, "You Clicked at "+calonSiswa.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      
     }
                   });

                   }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }
   }
}
```

and here's the php code which will fetch the data :

```js
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.php");

    //gets user's info based off of a username.
    $query = "SELECT no_pendaftaran,nama_lengkap FROM pendaftaran";
    
    
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        
        //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
        
    }
    
    //fetching all the rows from the query
 $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
 $arr['pendaftar'][]= $row;
    
    
 $json = json_encode($arr);

 $json_encoded_string = json_encode($arr);
 $json_encoded_string = str_replace("\\/", '/', $json_encoded_string);
 echo $json_encoded_string;

?>
```

PHP Output :

```
{"pendaftar":[[{"no_pendaftaran":"AD-15-001","nama_lengkap":"Wanda"}]]}
```

Comment: pendaftar = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
 JSonArray temp= pendaftar.getjsonArray(0);
 than using loop

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar you mean replace the loop?

Answer (score 1):

i finally able to show the array on listview, the problem is remain in my php code here:

```js
//fetching all the rows from the query
 $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
  
  //here, the problem is the bracket []
 $response["pendaftar"][]= $row;
  //here

 echo json_encode($response);
```

all i need to do is just remove the bracket, i figure it out by seeing someone else array output,
my php output is like this, there are double brackets [] :

```js
{"pendaftar":[[{"no_pendaftaran":"AD-15-001","nama_lengkap":"Wanda"},{"no_pendaftaran":"AD-15-002","nama_lengkap":"Skndje"},{"no_pendaftaran":"AD-15-003","nama_lengkap":"Aksn"}]]}
```

while other only got 1 bracket, i'm not sure the reason, but my problem solved, by myself.